# Geofencing sample app is not working with mock location

Tags: android, gps, notifications, maps, location

greetings

I have a ICE Cream sandwitch phone with google play service.

Installed the Geofencedetection sample app from the following
http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

I also installed a Mock Location application

Using this mock location i have set my location as new delhi (lat 28.66 long 77.21).

Now i registered the following geofences using the sample app

Geofence1
    lat 11.94898
    long 79.48475
    radius 1000 meters

Geofence2
    lat 77.00000
    long 77.00000
    radius 1000 meters

Now i again opened the mock location and set the 
location as (within geofence 1) my home.
    lat 11.94898
    long 79.48475

I have checked the mock location with the Maps application.
It displays correctly. I enabled the Allow Mock Locations
in Developer options

But the sample Geofence application is not triggering any
notification. I checked the code. As per the code it should send
notification when the user enters the geofence.

I could not understand why it is not sending notification.
Will this work only on real network?

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong?

Best Regards
jothi

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar experience using the sample MockLocation app from

http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html

For example if my geofence is set at 5,100 and I use the mocklocation app to inject a single mock location at 5,100, the geofence will not trigger.

However, if you repeatedly inject multiple mock locations at 5,100 the geofence will trigger. In my case, injecting mock locations at 5,100 three times consecutively caused my geofence to trigger. To be clear, when I say inject I mean doing:

```
mLocationClient.setMockLocation(yourMockLocation);
```

Everything below is pure speculation on my part so take it with a grain of salt:
My speculation is there is some filtering algorithm in the LocationClient backend whose purpose is to filter out spurious sensor values and it might be detecting that huge change in lat/long as a possible spurious value. Another possibility is the geofence simply doesnt trigger until it receives multiple readings that indicate you are within its vicinity.

Answer (score 1):

Please check notification of app when app in foreground because i am also not getting any update for geofence in background. But in foreground, It is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have stuck with this problem for sometime. Then eventually it turns out the google mock location tutorial (http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html) failed to mention you will need to set below two calls with the mock location you created:

```
    /*
        setElapsedRealtimeNanos() was added in API 17
     */
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        newLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
    }
    newLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Without these two calls my mock location won't trigger my geofence. After calling these my geofence is triggered without issues.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar experience with MockLocation app, just use a large number of seconds on "send interval" field, like 7 seconds, and the geofence will trigger.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a ton of time on this I finally figured out that the secret was to use the provider name "network" when creating the mock location instance.

```
Location location = new Location("network");
```